# How do I optimize an all-negative vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I only have n aggregated vectors $X: X_1,X_2,…,X_n$, which equal to:

$X_i=D_i+C~~i\in1,2,…,n$

Also, all elements in $D_i$ are greater than 0: $D_i>0$, all elements in $C$ are negative $C<0$. So, there are $n$ aggregation vectors $X_i$, $n$ all-positive vectors $D_i$, and only one all-negative vector $C$.

How can I find the optimum vector $C$:

$\arg\min_C~\|X-(D+C)\|_2^2$

Comment: What does optimum mean?

Comment: $\arg\min_C~\|X-(D+C)\|^2$

Comment: You might want to add that to the question and specify what norm you are using.

Comment: I have thought that the row minimum elements of all $X_i$ may provide the least error for $C$. But I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\|X-(D+C)\|_2^2 = \sum_k |X_k - (D_k+C_k)|^2$.

If we let $\hat{C}_k = \min(X_k-D_k,0)$, then 
$|X_k - (D_k+\hat{C}_k)| \le |X_k - (D_k+C_k)|$ for all $C_k$ and hence
$\|X-(D+\hat{C})\|_2^2 \le \|X-(D+C)\|_2^2$ for all $C$.